# How to run WSO2 ESB Samples in newer version?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm looking at WSO2 ESB samples http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/ESB+Samples+Setup

It tells me to use "./wso2esb-samples.sh -sn " to start ESB with different configurations. But I couldn't find wso2esb-samples.sh anywhere... How should I start ESB with different configuration?

And a side question, if I want to start ESB with multiple configrations, how should it be configured?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located inside `<ESB_HOME>/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Samples are given to provide information regarding the common use-cases  and to provide the experience the different features of the WSO2 ESB. Yes, you can configure the ESB with different configuration depend on your requirement, for that you can follow our ESB doc which gives all the information that you required...

Thanks,

Mohan